# Use UIActionsheet when click in the table cell

Tags: objective-c, uiactionsheet

I have a slide in menu called MenuViewController. In the menu there is a cell called alert. Im trying to make it so when you click on the cell alert it calls the method showActionSheet. When I try to drag the cell to the method in Storyboard it doesn't work.

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController{
    NSArray *menu;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    menu = @[@"first", @"second", @"third"];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [menu count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *cellIdentifier = [menu objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}


// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{


    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }



}

- (void)showActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Action Sheet Demo"; //Action Sheet Title
    NSString *destructiveTitle = @"Destructive Button"; //Action Sheet Button Titles
    NSString *other1 = @"Other Button 1";
    NSString *other2 = @"Other Button 2";
    NSString *other3 = @"Other Button 3";
    NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel Button";

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle
                                  otherButtonTitles:other1, other2, other3, nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    //Get the name of the current pressed button
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if  ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Destructive Button"]) {
        NSLog(@"Destructive pressed --> Delete Something");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 1"]) {
        NSLog(@"Other 1 pressed");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 2"]) {
        NSLog(@"Other 2 pressed");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Other Button 3"]) {
        NSLog(@"Other 3 pressed");
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel Button"]) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel pressed --> Cancel ActionSheet");
    }
}
```

Comment: but how do you call the method within that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget your method, try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Action Sheet Demo"; //Action Sheet Title
    NSString *destructiveTitle = @"Destructive Button"; //Action Sheet Button Titles
    NSString *other1 = @"Other Button 1";
    NSString *other2 = @"Other Button 2";
    NSString *other3 = @"Other Button 3";
    NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel Button";

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle
                                  otherButtonTitles:other1, other2, other3, nil];

    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: unknown receiver showActionSheet; did you mean UIActionSheet